# Rank and group in python to form 10 portfolios every month

Tags: python, sas, grouping, rank

I have a panel of stocks with these columns: Date, Ticker, Ret, MTB.
I want to rank the stocks based on the MTB value, every month, and put them into 10 groups. This procedure is needed when I want to make a portfolio.
I used to do this very easily in SAS using the following code:

---

```
proc rank data=dt out=dt group=10;
  by Date;
    var MTB;
    ranks MTB_Rank;
run;
```

---

In Python, however, I couldn't find a straightforward method to rank and group. I used the following method to rank and group by date but the answer is not satisfying!

```
***dt['MTB_Rank'] = dt.groupby(['Date'])['MTB'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q=10, labels=False, duplicates= 'drop'))***
```

The problem is that it doesn't create 10 groups for every date. Infact, it just creates 7 groups for the whole data and each date might only have some groups. I also cannot remove "duplicates= 'drop'" because then the code shows me an error that the Bin edges must be unique.
I would be thankful if you can guide me through this problem.
Thank you

[A picture of the data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JRcb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can't provide a oneliner, though
it's sometimes better to split into smaller steps.

**1. Sort your DataFrame properly**

```
df.sort_values(by=['Column1','Column2'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

**2. Create a simple iterator column (same as Rank):**

```
df['MTB_Rank'] = df.groupby(['name']).cumcount()+1
```

**3. Refresh group after threshold:**

```
df['MTB_Rank2'] = df.MTB_Rank.apply(lambda x: x - 10 if x > 10 else x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you please explain more about Step 3. What does it do?

Comment: @HamedYousefi 
1. You apply a lambda function with a given threshold (e.g. 10), the function checks each row of column MTB_Rank, deducts 10 IF value > 10, else writes the value unchanged.
2. I really recommend spending time on youtube  'lambda functions python' - works like a charm